# My view seems to not resize height although it should?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

The view is set for "Retina 3.5 full screen"

At the bottom is a button, that is set to track the bottom of the view (outer top, outer left and outer bottom strut set).

This code is in the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view bounds];
    CGFloat height = viewRect.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Screen is %g pixels high", height);
}
```

When I run it in the simulator set for iPhone 3.5" I get a height of 480 pixels and the button stays where it is.

When I run it in the 4" simulator I would expect a taller view, and that the button moved to flush with the bottom. Yet it does not. BUT the view is visibly expanding to fill out the whole screen of the simulator, despite the code claiming that the view is still only 480 pixels tall.

What can I check for? I would prefer not to have to write code to relocate the button...

Comment: Have you tried checking the view's bounds in `-viewWillAppear:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the size inspector tab within utilities within XCode you should see the autosizing options under the 'View' section.
Ensuring your UIView is configured to expand in all directions should see its height increase when using the retina 4 screen:

**Expanding UIView**

[image: Expanding UIView]

Secondly, the autosizing options allows you to set which side the UIView is anchored to (the red lines outside of the grey box). By anchoring your UIButton to the bottom, and not the top, it should maintain its distance from the bottom of its superview during resizing:

**UIView anchored to bottom**

[image: UIView anchored to bottom]

Comment: Excellent! I had totally overlooked the anchoring to the top for the button.

Answer (score -2):

view frame remains same for iPhone 5 and previous models.

instead **UIScreen bounds change**

you can check for iPhone 5 by

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    // iPhone Classic
}
else
{
    // iPhone 5
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. Of course your view size will be different when it's fullscreen on an iPhone 5 vs an iPhone 4.

Comment: i have the above by my experience..so it is true. if you think view size will be different then why does the `NSLog` outputs otherwise in the question..view frame and bounds remains same..`[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds` change for iPhone 5

Comment: If your screen size is bigger your view size will be bigger, too. It's that easy. Are you seriously trying to convince me that a fullscreen view will be 480 points tall on the iPhone 5?? Good luck man...

Comment: who said I was trying to convince you..lol.. i have solved the issue like this with my solution above..if you don't understand solution..I suggest you keep quiet..you have not proved me still why nslog still prints 480. for 4 in simulator..so I don't think you have any experience in this issue. I have a theory which I tested.

Comment: And if you don't understand the question you shouldn't answer in the first place. The view's bounds is 480 points tall in -viewDidLoad, because that's the size the view has in the xib. It'll be resized after -viewDidLoad and the bounds will be 568 points tall in -viewWillAppear:. Your statement that the view's frame is the same for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 is just wrong, that's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: it aint wrong.. all dynamic initialization of views are mostly done at startup of `ViewDiDLoad` and the frame doesn't change there..my solution is there.. my solution is much better since dynamically initializing and setting position each time on `viewWillAppear` is overkill.if you are thinking about going out of general practice..please point out next time!